# Displaying gstreamer in Oculus Rift

Tags: gstreamer, oculus

So I have a fisheye camera piped through gstreamer, over the internet to another pc where I want to display it on an Oculus Rift.  The Oculus expects a 1280×800 resolution input just like a normal monitor, but the left 640×800 of the screen displays in the left eye, other 640×800 for right eye.

I need to modify this:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false`

to show the stream twice, side-by-side.  If I run this command and I winKey+leftArrow, it displays really well in one eye.  The oculus even crops out edges (read: windows decorations).  But gstreamer won't let me run gst-launch twice at the same time.  Any way to make it work?  Admittedly, it's quite a hack, but it seemed to work quite well in the one eye.

Alternatively, can someone help me use videomixer?

windows 8, btw'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to duplicate the video with a

```
... ! tee name=t ! queue ! videomixer name=m sink_0::xpos=0 sink_1::xpos=640 ! ... t. ! queue ! m.
```

the key is to use the videomixers pad properties to position the copies.

Comment: After having read a decent amount of gstreamer documentation, I still don't know where to insert this.  Could you help me out?  From what I understand, tee will split the stream and define 't' as the reference.  Then videomixer will mix together 't' and 't' at x-coords 0 and 640.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! ! tee name=t ! queue ! videomixer name=m sink_0::xpos=0 sink_1::xpos=640 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false t. ! queue ! m